# Function affecting multiple tabs on page- Jquery

Tags: jquery, html, filter, tabs

I have this code that filters a table based on user input. However, its removing content of *another* table on a *different* tab on my page. I know its the table selector that causing the problem. I tried adjusting the "tr:not(:has(>th))" to be the ID of the specific table I am trying to filter and the add/remove class with no luck. How can I have this function run properly for the current tab/table I am in without it changing the other tabs content?

```
  userinp = $('#term').val();
        $("tr:not(:has(>th))").each(function() {
            if (~$(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(userinp.toLowerCase() ) ) {
                $(this).show();
            } else {
                $(this).hide();
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved my own problem.

I just changed

```
tr:not(:has(>th))
```

to

```
table:visible tr:not(:has(>th))
```

in the table selector so it will only look for visible tables.